# Nginx add_header does not work | cloudflare?

Tags: nginx, cookies, cloudflare

I'm using cloudflare and want to add a cookie to my pages, but it does not work.
I have searched the internet for hours but couldnt find anything.

My config:

```
server {
    client_max_body_size    10M;
    listen 80;
    listen 443;

    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/domain/domain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/domain/domain.key;

    server_name  domain en.domain de.domain;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.error.log;
    root   /var/www;
    index  index.php index.html;
    location / {
        if ($http_host ~ "^en\.domain\.com$"){
            add_header Set-Cookie "lang=en;Domain=.domain.com;Path=/;Max-Age=31536000";
        }
        auth_basic            "Restricted Area";
        auth_basic_user_file  conf.d/htpasswd;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

I don't have other `add_header` in my code.

Comment: Show full server block

Comment: I have added the full server block.. I have solved the problem now with passing variables through php but i'm interested in a solution with cookies..